# Match lines and extract content in one go

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I'd like to find lines with `h2` and `p` and get the content between the tags ...

```
<main>Nothing</main>
<h2>Hello</h2><p>World</p>
<h2>Bells</h2><p>Walls</p>
<h2>Jelly</h2><p>Minus</p>
<p>Fluff</p>
```

... into a tab separated list:

```
Hello World
Bells Walls
Jelly Minus
```

I currently use:

```
grep -E "<h2>(.*)<\/h2><p>(.*)<\/p>" | sed -E "s/<h2>(.*)<\/h2><p>(.*)<\/p>/\1 \2/"
```

However, I find it sort of annoying that I have to first `grep <pattern>` and then do `sed <the same pattern>`. Is it possible to do this using a single utility, using the pattern only once?

Comment: You could do all your string matching and substitution with python or Perl etc in ‘one action’. But it’s not really clear what you mean by a single action? One process? One thread? One program?

Comment: Is that the actual file or just a part of a file or an example? If you want that exact result then you can use the following long-winded code and modify it to suit your needs: `cat input | awk 'NR==2,NR==4' | sed 's/<h2>//' | sed 's/<\/h2><p>/ \t/' | sed 's/<\/p>//' > file2` It's one command but not one action although what you exactly want is not entirely clear.

Comment: `grep` is to search for strings and can't be used to replace strings. You'll need `sed` for the latter.

Comment: In answer to the modified post, yes you could do this all in one go. I would suggest making a little python script (or whatever language you prefer) and create a compiled regex with the `re` module. I’m not at my computer right now to have a go at it, so I’ll leave this as a comment for now.

Comment: I was going to ask the very same question... Since this is for Bash script switching to perl/python for this isn't really worth it.  @Joe I think the OP means one single command, and expressing the pattern only once (DRY principle).

Comment: Try `sed -n ... /p“`

Answer (score 2):

Using an XML parser is a really good idea, but if you can't use one for some reason (the file is not well-formed, you don't have any parsers installed, etc.), you can use PERL for this:

```
$ perl -ne 'if(/<h2>(.*?)<\/h2><p>(.*?)<\/p>/){print "$1\t$2\n"}' filename.ext
Hello   World
Bells   Walls
Jelly   Minus
```

I prefer using lazy matches so that I don't get unintended results:

**test.txt**

```
<h1>Nothing</h1>
<h2>Hello</h2><p>World</p><h2>Goodbye</h2><p>Earth</p>
<h2>Bells</h2><p>Walls</p>
<h2>Jelly</h2><p>Minus</p>
<h3>Zip</h3>

$ perl -ne 'if(/<h2>(.*?)<\/h2><p>(.*?)<\/p>/){print "$1\t$2\n"}' test.txt
Hello   World
Bells   Walls
Jelly   Minus
$ perl -ne 'if(/<h2>(.*)<\/h2><p>(.*)<\/p>/){print "$1\t$2\n"}' test.txt
Hello</h2><p>World</p><h2>Goodbye       Earth
Bells   Walls
Jelly   Minus
```

As you can see, only using a regular expression isn't going to get all the cases that a domain-specific tool will. If you're OK with that, then that's fine; just be aware that you may get inaccurate results if the input doesn't match your pattern exactly!

Comment: This is as short as you could hope for. Is it possible to make a generalised solution where you can have any number of fields tab separated without having to explicitly type `$1\t$2...$n`?

Answer (score 1):

The right way with **`xmlstarlet`** tool (for parsing xml/html data):

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//h2' -v 'concat(., "'$'\t''", ./following-sibling::p)' -n file
```

The output:

```
Hello   World
Bells   Walls
Jelly   Minus
```

Comment: I get `Extra content at the end of the document:` at the first character of `<h2>Hello</h2>...`. I agree about XML parsing but XPath has a beginner's threshold. I'd be very interested in a lightweight XML extractor with a simple syntax, like `find("a").href` to get all links in a document. Is there such a tool that comes with most standard distros?

Comment: @forthrin, there shouldn't be any errors if your tags are in the `root`(parent) tag. `Python` provides a flexible functional syntax when searching though xml/html, but it requires more code. But the main thing you should keep in mind that `sed`, `grep` and alike are NOT a good choice for xml/html processing

Answer (score 1):

For the regex you use, which contains unquoted `()`, needs Extended Regex syntax (or replace each `(` and `)` with `\(` and `\)`). That's simple.

And, probably avoid a greedy matching too much using `[^<]` instead of a dot.

Of course, you can set a variable and play with quotes using **only** sed:

```
$ a='<h2>([^<]*)<\/h2><p>([^<]*)<\/p>'                                                                    
$ sed -nE '/'"$a"'/s/'"$a"'/\1 \2/p' infile
```

But it gets better as this could be simplified. Sed remembers the last regex used and a left side of `s//` (empty) is enougth.

```
$ sed -nE '/'"$a"'/s//\1 \2/p' infile
```

Or, without variable:

```
$ sed -nE '/<h2>([^<]*)<\/h2><p>([^<]*)<\/p>/s//\1 \2/p' infile
Hello World
Bells Walls
Jelly Minus
```

Comment: I like the brevity, but I get: `"/<h2>([^<]*)<\/h2><p>([ ...": extra characters at the end of p command`. BSD sed May 10, 2005.

Comment: @forthrin There was a typo in the last expression, corrected. Tested with GNU sed, should also work with BSD sed.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution via `sed`:

```
sed 's/<[^13>]*>/ /g' test | sed 's/<h[13]>.*<\/h[13]>//' <file>

 Hello  World
 Bells  Walls
 Jelly  Minus
```

Second `sed` just removes unnecessary tags (`<h1>` or `<h3>`).

Pattern explanation:

`/<[^13>]*>/ /` - search for any `*` symbols in text that begins with `<` and ends with `>`. But between the tags the symbols `1` or `3` **must not** (`^`) be present.

Comment: This works in this particular sample, but would struggle if other non-interesting content was introduced to the text.